# Unrecognized Selector Error However Selector Doesn't Exist

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, iboutlet, unrecognized-selector

I am having an issue where I get this error when I run my app in the simulator:

```
-[ViewController verify:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75ca600
2013-08-08 09:31:14.890 Mathy[32061:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController verify:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75ca600'
```

The issue though is that the selector it refers to does not even exist in the program.  Here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    float result;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *number1Label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *number2Label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet
UILabel *op;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *userInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CorrectOrWrong;
-(IBAction)generateQuestion:(id)sender;
@end



@implementation ViewController
@synthesize questionType;
@synthesize number1Label;
@synthesize number2Label;
@synthesize op;
@synthesize userInput;
@synthesize CorrectOrWrong;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.CorrectOrWrong.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)generateQuestion:(id)sender
{
    self.CorrectOrWrong.hidden = YES;
    self.questionType.text = @"";
    self.number1Label.text = @"";
    self.number2Label.text = @"";
    self.op.text = @"";
    self.userInput.text = @"";

    number1 = arc4random_uniform(21);
    number2 = arc4random_uniform(21);
    int operation = arc4random_uniform(4);
    switch (operation) {
        case 0:
            result = number1+number2;
            self.questionType.text = @"Addition";
            self.number1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number1];
            self.number2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2];
            self.op.text = @"+";
            break;
        case 1:
            result = number1-number2;
            self.questionType.text = @"Subtraction";
            self.number1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number1];
            self.number2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2];
            self.op.text = @"-";
            break;
        case 2:
            result = number1*number2;
            self.questionType.text = @"Multiplication";
            self.number1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number1];
            self.number2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2];
            self.op.text = @"*";
            break;
        case 3:
            result = number1/number2;
            self.questionType.text = @"Division";
            self.number1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number1];
            self.number2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2];
            self.op.text = @"÷";
            break; 
        default: result=number1+number2;
            self.questionType.text = @"Addition";
            self.number1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number1];
            self.number2Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number2];
            self.op.text = @"+";
            break;
}
```

}

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if([self.userInput.text intValue])
    {
        self.CorrectOrWrong.hidden = NO;
        self.CorrectOrWrong.text = @"Great Job!";
    }
    else
    {
        self.CorrectOrWrong.hidden = NO;
        self.CorrectOrWrong.text = @"Uh oh! Incorrect!";  
    }

    return YES;
}
```

@end

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Also, do a find in project for "verify".

Comment: I did add an exception breakpoint.  There is no verify selector.  Did a command-f

Comment: What line is Xcode stopping you on?

Comment: @user2643829 OK, add an exception breakpoint. It will stop on the line causing the problem.

Comment: It's stopping right here: @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
This is denoted by a SIGABRT

Comment: I hate it when Xcode does that. Does it stop on launch?

Comment: A command + F only searches within that one file. Search throughout your project by clicking the magnifying glass icon in the navigator (or command + 3)

Comment: @BoA: This can often be alleviated by adding an exception breakpoint.

Comment: @Scott Often but not always. He said he added an exception breakpoint.

Comment: @BoA when I press the UIButton for generateQuestion: it fails

Comment: @Scott I did a search.  No verify.  Followed your instructions

Comment: Double check your outlets in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Will you please delete the instance of the app from the simulator or device, then re-run the app again?

Comment: @BoA I accounted for that.  I saw what elements were connected to.

Comment: @shuvo I did that already.  Just did it again.  No difference.

Comment: I also faced same issue once. But completely forgot how I fix that as it was long ago. I'm pretty sure if you switch your same code into another project, you wnt get the error. It's very weird.

Comment: @shuvo I tried duplicating the project.  That didn't work.  Are you saying start an entirely new project, redefine the Storyboard stuff and then copy and paste the code from the original project to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that selector verify: was sent to an instance of ViewController. In most cases, this means the message was intended for some other object, but that object was deallocated too early and an instance of ViewController was allocated at the same address.

The Zombies instrument should help find the object that was deallocated too early. If your have a -verify: method somewhere else in your project, then the deallocated object may be an instance of that class.